# Why is phonegap app not making sound on Samsung with Android 4?

Tags: audio, phonegap-plugins, howler.js

I have a phonegap app, which is now in alpha testing of PlayStore.
The sound works on most devices, but not on Samsung Devices with Android 4.x.
I didn't find an issue or similar questions. Did I do something wrong?

Code with https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/2.0

```js
  var sound = new Howl({
    src: ['res/raw/warning.mp3']
  }).play();
```

My code with Cordova-plugin-media:

```js
  var src = "res/raw/warning.mp3";
  // HTML5 Audio
  if (typeof Audio != "undefined") { 
   new Audio(src).play() ;

  // Phonegap media
  } else if (typeof device != "undefined") {

   // Android needs the search path explicitly specified
   if (device.platform == 'Android') {
    src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
   }

   var mediaRes = new Media(src,
    function onSuccess() {
     // release the media resource once finished playing
     mediaRes.release();
    },
    function onError(e){
     alert("error playing sound: " + JSON.stringify(e));
    });
   mediaRes.play();

  } else {
   alert("no sound API to play: " + src);
  }
```

Anyone an idea what is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple of things here; ideally, you should wait for the sound be to loaded before trying to play it (Howler tries to handle this itself, but it doesn't always work)

From their examples

```
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['sound.webm', 'sound.mp3']
});

// Clear listener after first call.
sound.once('load', function(){
  sound.play();
});
```

The second issue may be because it's an older android device, and thus WebAudio support may be sketchy. Try adding html5 into the options

```
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['sound.webm', 'sound.mp3', 'sound.wav'],
  html5 : true
});
```

The last issue could be because a lot of mobile devices require a user interaction before they can play a sound (think of browser makers not wanting people to browse to websites and having music automatically start playing!). So once the sound has loaded, request the user to touch the screen once, and then play a sound on that touch event. This should 'unlock' the audio from now on. Again, Howler does try to do this, but it's something you may want to look at as well.

Comment: tapping on screen isnt possible, because its an app, that tries to detect unconsciousness. But I will try the other tipps. Thanks!

Comment: html5 makes it not working on Android5, and waiting for load didnt change anything :(

Comment: changing to cordova-plugin-media didn't change anything too. Again no sound on Samsung with Android 4 - but better with Android 6 on Samsung!